# PHP: I want to know how to send a POST request with everything in this json for my PHP SERVER

Tags: php

This is for my personal sharex imagehost.

```
{
  "Version": "14.1.0",
  "Name": "Discord post",
  "DestinationType": "ImageUploader",
  "RequestMethod": "POST",
  "RequestURL": "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/CHANNEL HERE/messages",
  "Headers": {
    "authorization": "Discord Token here"
  },
  "Body": "MultipartFormData",
  "Arguments": {
    "content": null,
    "tts": "false"
  },
  "FileFormName": "file",
  "URL": "{json:['attachments'][0]['url']}",
  "ThumbnailURL": "{json:['attachments'][0]['url']}"
}
```

This json is a sharex custom uploader*

I also want to get a response too.
Please write down the code for me bc im new to php with post requests.

I tried looking at multiple answered questions and I couldn't find one that shows how to use headers and other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found out discord rate-limited my website for some reason.